# How to use OS Sampler in jmeter for remote script

Tags: linux, jmeter, remote-access

I am facing an issue in jmeter that I want to know if I can solve.
I need to run a script in distance computer.
when I run the script via command line in my computer it is working.

```
plink -ssh jenkins@178.27.288.288 -pw passtest  sudo /opt/test/test.sh
```

I want to run it in Jmeter from my computer (the same as the script run).
I tried the ssh sampler that did not work
I want to useage the OS sampler, Is it can be done? Can I run script on distance computer?
The only explanation I found was from blazemeter site, and mentioned:
"Again, since running the “plink” program via the OS Process Sampler is quite easy,"

remote machine: jenkins@178.27.288.288,
password for remote machine: passtest,
command: sudo /opt/test/test.sh

So can someone please advise

I added the OS sampler

[image]

and get this message:

```
Exception occurred whilst executing system call: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "sudo /opt/test/test.sh" (in directory "plink -ssh jenkins@178.27.288.288 -pw passtest "): CreateProcess error=267, The directory name is invalid
```

Can someone please advise how to run the command in the remote computer?
once again if I take the full line into command command line it is working, but after I cut it for Jmeter it is not working? what am I missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Command arguments need to go in the "Command parameters" section, not in the "Working Directory"
2. I would suggest running your script via [cmd.exe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe) interpreter, so the actual command would be `cmd`, not the Linux command
3. It is more safe to provide `-hostkey` parameter as if the remote Linux machine is not in [known_hosts](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/host-key) your script will get stuck

   Assuming all above your OS Process Sampler configuration should look like:

   [image: JMeter OS Process Sampler for plink]

---

It might be easier to use [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) where you can invoke a program and get the output as easy as:

```
"c:\somefolder\plink.exe -pw passtest sudo /opt/test/test.sh".execute().text
```

More information on the approach: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: Hey Dimitry I tried the OS process and it is not working.  I want to use the jsr223.  If I understand what you wrote is to use JSR223 and write c:\place of plink\plink.exe -pw password to server "the script".execute().text.   I should also mentioned the remote server, since it is not in my computer

Comment: Thanks a lot Dimitry I try now the OS process sampler, and added the /c in the top  of the command variable and it is worked